# MODX - Template variable that hides post author when checked

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, modx-templates

So I am using the add-on articles to create a press release section on my site. I need to create a template variable that is a check box and if checked it will NOT show the post author:

```
[[*publishedby:userinfo=`username`]]
```

What is the best way for me to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your checkbox tv input option value like "`Hide==1`" then use [output filter](https://docs.modx.com/revolution/2.x/making-sites-with-modx/customizing-content/input-and-output-filters-(output-modifiers)) like this:

```
[[*your_tv:ne=`1`:then=`[[*publishedby:userinfo=`username`]]`]]
```

Comment: as vasis said ~ should work fine. though remember to set a default when creating the TV as the TV will not actually exist if not defined on a resource and a default is not set.  (a little modx quirk)

Comment: absolutely perfect!